# Problem on halfplanes

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry

Let F be a finite collection of halfplanes covering the plane. Prove that there
are three halfplanes of F covering the plane.

So I understand that half-planes are formed when a line divides the plane resulting in either right or left half-plane(if vertically) or upper and lower half-plane (if horizontally). So I see that there are three parts i.e. the line dividing the plane and the two half-planes that forms. So according to the definition itself any multiple line division(let's say vertical division) will always result in right and left half-planes. But how do I prove it? Is my approach correct?

Comment: Nowhere in your problem it says that those lines must be "vertical" or "horizontal".

Comment: See https://f2.org/maths/halfplane-soln.html . The problem is not easy.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you so much. I am going through it. I thought it was easy. But now going through the link I think I got it all wrong. Man! "not easy" does not even begin to describe the feeling that I am getting right now while looking at the solution.

Comment: Good luck......

Comment: Here is an „alternative“ idea: Note that the half-planes cover the plane if and only if the intersection of their complements is empty (except for some corner cases where the intersection of the bounding lines is not empty - this can only happen if all the lines go through the same point). Now, using Helly‘s theorem, it can be derived that if the intersection of all complements is rmpty, then there must be some 3 complements whose intersection is also empty.

Comment: @PatrickSchnider sounds good. I will try to implement this idea also.

Comment: @Dasha FYI Patrick's approach is how I've seen this problem done. Given your posts, it would be helpful for you to read up on Helly's theorem and it's various basic applications. There's likely a textbook/lecture notes that will cover most of what you've posted.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, I am actually having discrete geometry as one of my subjects. And I am following lectures notes on discrete and polyhedral geometry by Igor Park. But since my background is in engineering, I have a lot of gaps to be filled like I have to study real analysis, topology and maybe complex analysis to understand completely. I have started with real analysis and have brushed up some basics of topology. But still, it is difficult for me to understand Igor Park

Comment: @CalvinLin if you can advise me what else to follow to perfectly understand it and master it, it will be really helpful. I have had posted the same question but have not received any substantial answers. So its all hit and trial method right now.